# Maven Surefire Plugin "include" option for Groovy sources

Tags: maven, groovy, maven-surefire-plugin

I have Groovy project and I want to control by Surefire which tests to execute ([sample repo](https://github.com/mkordas/maven-surefire-groovy)).

Assuming I have test `ExampleTest` I can configure Surefire as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/ExampleTest.*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can also use `<include>ExampleTest.*</include>` or `<include>ExampleTest</include>` and it works.

Unfortunately I cannot configure it as `<include>ExampleTest.groovy</include>`, but it **works for `<include>ExampleTest.java</include>`!**

Why it works like that? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the regex support in the `<include>` patterns as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

For example, to include the `ExampleTest.groovy` file:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>%regex[ExampleTest\.groovy]</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can say it's a bug. You can't use `.groovy` in inclusion list. But it will work if you use `.*`, `.java` or `.class`.